# Why is same Stored Procedure call triggered multiple times

Tags: c#, javascript, sql

In my web page when I add a record, some records are added multiple times. Then I found out that the same DB call is sent more than once(when profiling). Not just that SP, but also some other SPs. But they are only returning data. So they are not causing any issues. But this behavior is remaining only in Production site. Not in the development site. Therefore it is really hard to track where the SP call is coming from. I checked for loops and stuff but there is none.

Here is the HTTP request in javascript file:

```
var strParams = "?";
strParams += "Process="           + "assignQuestion";                               
...
strParams += "&measure="          + measure;

xmlAssignQuestion = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlAssignQuestion .onreadystatechange = assignQuestionBack;
xmlAssignQuestion .open("POST", "AssignQuestion.reliability" + strParams, false);
xmlAssignQuestion .send();
```

---

Here is the HTTP handler

```
if (process.Equals("assignQuestion"))
{
    int measure = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["measure"]);

    string ret = DBClasses.AssignToGroup.storeQuestionp(measure);

    if (long.Parse(ret) == -1)
        context.Response.Write("f");
    else context.Response.Write(ret);

    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the profiler dump screen?

Comment: Debug using fiddler to monitor network traffic and make sure that duplicate http requests are not being sent.

Comment: Are you sure your users are not clicking a SUBMIT button multiple times? If they are you can always write some javascript code to prevent it.

Comment: profiler dump screen would be very long because second call occur after few mins. But I'll try to get one.

Comment: SP is called more than once for sure because I confirmed it after profiling. And SUBMIT button is not clicked multiple times either. Because I do not get the return alert multiple times. It is like the SP call is started from somewhere in the middle of the process. I used the script debugger and found out that JavaScript function is called only once.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the production data from getting corrupted I would add a unique constraint to the appropriate column combination to ensure that the duplicates cannot occur. Upon adding the constraint the next time a client operation attempts to insert duplicate they will receive an error and this will help identify the scenario that causes it to occur.

Comment: No that won't help because in my case that query is used to add a new record and the identifier is not yet generated. So there is no way I can check whether it is already added.